# Calculate Pi algorithm from a tutorial using OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am studying [this](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf) tutorial about OpenMP and I came across this exercise, on page 19. It is a pi calculation algorithm which I have to parallelize:

```
static long num_steps = 100000;
double step;
void main ()
{
  int i;
  double x, pi
  double sum = 0.0;
  step = 1.0 / (double)num_steps;

  for(i = 0; i < num_steps; i++)
  {
     x = (I + 0.5) * step;
     sum = sum + 4.0 / (1.0 + x*x);
  }

  pi = step * sum;
}
```

I can not use, up to this point, #pragma parallel for. I can only use:

```
#pragma omp parallel {}
omp_get_thread_num();
omp_set_num_threads(int);
omp_get_num_threads();
```

My implementation looks like this :

```
#define NUM_STEPS 800

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int num_steps = NUM_STEPS;
   int i;
  double x;
  double pi;
  double step = 1.0 / (double)num_steps;

  double sum[num_steps];

  for(i = 0; i < num_steps; i++)
  {
      sum[i] = 0;
  }

  omp_set_num_threads(num_steps);
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    x = (omp_get_thread_num() + 0.5) * step;
    sum[omp_get_thread_num()] += 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
  }

  double totalSum = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < num_steps; i++)
  {
    totalSum += sum[i];
  }

  pi = step * totalSum;

  printf("Pi: %.5f", pi);
}
```

Ignoring the problem by using an sum array (It explains later that it needs to define a critical section for the sum value with #pragma omp critical or #pragma omp atomic), the above impelentation only works for a limited number of threads (800 in my case), where the serial code uses 100000 steps. Is there a way to achieve this with only the aforementioned OpenMP commands, or am I obliged to use #pragma omp parallel for, which hasn't been mentioned yet in the tutorial?

Thanks a lot for your time, I am really trying to grasp the concept of parallelization in C using OpenMP.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `#pragma omp atomic`?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic It is explained later the usefulness of #pragma omp atomic, but only regarding sum value. How can I use it to solve the "too many threads" issue? Is there a way, without having to use parallel for?

Comment: This tutorial is regularly sending confused learners to StackOverflow. I suggest you look for a learning material that follows a more idiomatic high-level approach instead of explaining OpenMP bottom-up. Maybe it works if you are getting a live-workshop, but it definitely does not when reading/watching the material online.

Comment: @Zulan [ad]Stackoverflow: turning confusion to knowledge since 2008 :-D[/ad]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to find a way to make your parallel algorithm somewhat independent from the number of threads.

The most simple way is to do something like:

```
int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
int n_threads = omp_get_num_threads();

for (int i = tid; i < num_steps; i += n_threads) {
    // ...
}
```

This way the work is split across all threads regardless of the number of threads.

If there were 3 threads and 9 steps:

- Thread 0 would do steps 0, 3, 6
- Thread 1 would do steps 1, 4, 7
- Thread 2 would do steps 2, 5, 8

This works but isn't ideal if each thread is accessing data from some shared array. It is better if threads access sections of data nearby for [locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) purposes.

In that case you can divide the number of steps by the number of threads and give each thread a contiguous set of tasks like so:

```
int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
int n_threads = omp_get_num_threads();

int steps_per_thread = num_steps / n_threads;
int start = tid * steps_per_thread;
int end = start + steps_per_thread;

for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Now the 3 threads performing 9 steps looks like:

- Thread 0 does steps 0, 1, 2
- Thread 1 does steps 3, 4, 5
- Thread 2 does steps 6, 7, 8

This approach is actually what is most likely happening when `#pragma omp for` is used. In most cases the compiler just divides the tasks according to the number of threads and assigns each thread a section.

So given a set of 2 threads and a 100 iteration for loop, the compiler would likely give iterations 0-49 to thread 0 and iterations 50-99 to thread 1.

Note that if the number of iterations does not divide evenly by the number of threads the remainder needs to be handled explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very useful answer since it helps me to clarify the "inner workings" of parallelization regarding functionalities such as #pragma omp parallel for.